# Adding a H1 Tag to Post Tags automatically, but hide the tag? (Same for Category)

Tags: categories, tags, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

So to increase my SEO score I require all tag pages to have a H1 title, for example `website.com/tags/taghere` would need the title: `<h1>TagHere</h1>` or simply `<h1>taghere</h1>`

I can go through each tag manually and add them but this would beyond tiresome to do for 1000+ tags, we're running the Avada theme and I can't see any option anywhere to do this automatically.

Is there a way I can create a function for the functions.php to do it automatically?

Essentially I want to do the same as what you see:

Hopefully someone can advise a solution, this would then also be usable for categories too.

[image]

Comment: Guess you can output hidden h1 tag on tag page template, instead of typing it for every tag manually.

Comment: The only php files under my child theme are "functions.php", "header.php", "footer.php" and under "template" folder there is another "header.php"

Comment: Can this hidden h1 tag with term name be pasted just after open body tag ?

Comment: @anton I don't see why not, it's hidden so it'll do nothing visually...

Comment: Keep in mind most search engines can tell when something is hidden, so it's doubtful that adding hidden H1s will have any impact on your actual rankings - even if whatever you're using to "grade" each page gives you a nice green checkmark because technically there is one in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom action in `function.php`, which checks current page type (if it's category or tag page).

   ```
   function hidden_term_name_action() {

       if( is_category() || is_tag() ){

           $term_id = get_queried_object_id();
           $term = get_term($term_id);
           if($term){
               echo sprintf('<h1 style="display:none;">%s</h1>', esc_attr($term->name));
           }
       }

   }

   add_action('hidden_term_name', 'hidden_term_name_action');
   ```
2. Paste this code in `header.php`, which fires this action and pastes term title inside hidden h1 tag.

   ```
   <?php do_action('hidden_term_name'); ?>
   ```

P.S. Not tested, but give it a try.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't appear to do anything. No errors, nothing.

Comment: Did you inspect page's source code? To check if this custom action works, you may add `else` to if statement and echo something to check if `get_term` returns something or not. On my localhost it works well.

Comment: You're missing a bracket are you not? } is missing. I just checked my theme and it shows unexpected end of file

Comment: yeap, first if statement is not closed